# Remove the lines starting with a character in shell

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have dataset as:

```
file.txt
de
fds
fds
a
sa
1
2
3
1
}
```

I would like to delete all the lines starting with characters or special characters. So my outfile is:

```
out.txt
1
2
3
1
```

I could do it manually with 'sed', but I am looking for a suitable command for this.

my code:

```
sed -i '/d//g' file.txt
sed -i '/f//g' file.txt
sed -i '/a//g' file.txt
sed -i '/s//g' file.txt
sed -i '/}//g' file.txt
```

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Comment: Thanks @ghoti for pointing out this. I have added my code.

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: `sed -n '/^[0-9]/p' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep` with `-E` option for regex (or egrep in short):

```
grep -E "^[0-9].*" file.txt
```

Comment: No need for the `-E` for this regular expression. It's a BRE in addition to ERE. Also, you might want to consider defaulting to single quotes except in cases where you know you need to quote variables. Just a general safety measure and good habit.

Comment: That's right, minimal answer would be "grep '^[0-9]' file.txt". However, I took the opportunity to show that grep could do more than that ;)

Comment: @R.Saban .. Would you please suggest me a modification of this script, if I need to preserve the negative values. I have asked this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006897/remove-the-lines-starting-with-a-character-in-shell-but-preserve-the-negative-v

Answer (score 2):

just keep lines starting with a number:

```
$ sed -i.bak -r '/^[0-9]/!d' filename
```

or delete lines starting with specific characters:

```
$ sed -i.bak -r '/^[dfas}]/d' filename
```