# Remove the lines starting with a character in shell, but preserve the negative values

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep

I have dataset as:

```
file.txt
de
fds
fds
a
sa
 -1
 2
 -3
 1
}
```

I would like to delete all the lines starting with characters or special characters, but preserve the negative values. So my outfile is:

```
out.txt
-1
2
-3
1
```

This question is related to one of my earlier questions [Remove the lines starting with a character in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448454/remove-the-lines-starting-with-a-character-in-shell) with which I can remove all lines starting with a character including negative sign.

I need to modify my code.

my code:

```
grep -E "^[0-9].*" file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
grep '^ *[-+]\?[0-9]\+' file.txt > out.txt
```

(Or)

```
grep -E '^ *[-+]?[0-9]+' file.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am sorry that I have space before the numbers. So it is removing all the values... I have modified my question

Comment: @Kay, Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -E '^[-| ][0-9]' file.txt > out
$ cat out
-1
 2
-3
 1
```